# Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure without error

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins

We have a jenkins server. We try to run a back-up job which contains only one command. I will upload the content of our `/var/jenkins_home` directory to an S3 bucket:

Command:

```
aws s3 cp --recursive /var/jenkins_home s3://our-bucket/backup-`date -I`
```

The logs show the right things. And my folder is inside the bucket:
Logs:

```
Completed 12872 of 12875 part(s) with 3 file(s) remaining
upload: ../../../war/xx/xx/xx/xx.js to s3://our-bucket/backup-2016-05-18/war/scripts/xx/xx/xx.js
Completed 12873 of 12875 part(s) with 2 file(s) remaining
upload: ../../../xx/xx/xx to s3://our-bucket/backup-2016-05-18/xx/xx/xx/xx
Completed 12874 of 12875 part(s) with 1 file(s) remaining
upload: ../../../xx/xx.jar to s3://our-bucket/backup-2016-05-18/xx/xx.jar
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Why am I getting a failure?

Comment: not sure - did you try `sync` instead, I always use sync after I had issue with cp recursive `aws s3 sync /var/jenkins_home s3://our-bucket/backup-`date -I`

Comment: Check what code is returned by aws and what its meaning is. Eventually handle the returnvalue in the execute shell to adjust build status as needed.

Comment: Do the files get uploaded? Do you a plugin for parsing the Jenkins output to mark builds as success/failure

Comment: Check also [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/topic/return-codes.html) on how to display and interpret aws exitcodes.

Comment: @FrédéricHenri I tried the sync but still the same issue.

Comment: @DominikGebhart I tried to check the return code but did not get it. I performed 'echo $?' after my aws command but it failed before it. I tried debug mode but saw only http 200 responses.

Comment: Errors for the shell command doesn't necessarily written at the end of the script. try opening the "full console output" and search for error, failure, failed, etc. maybe there was an error during the process and the overall run will be set to failure.